# why does python decorator make a function to return "None"?

Tags: python, decorator, wrapper

Guys can someone help me to understand why doesn't my python decorator work properly?

created a decorator that would print the below mentioned text  after returning the count of  car_fuel() function.

```
def decor(func):
    def wrapper(a):
        func(a)
        print('Bring 10 coupons and get a gallon of fuel for free')
    return wrapper



@decor
def car_fuel(a):
    b={'petrol':3.6,'diesel':3} #types of fuel and prices
    count = 0
    for i in a.keys():
        if i in b.keys():
            count+= a[i]*b[i]
    return count


abc={'petrol':10} # the fuel that i wanna buy and gallons
print(car_fuel(abc))
```

I want to have the following result:

> 36 
>   Bring 10 coupons and get a gallon of fuel for free

but what I get is:

> Bring 10 coupons and get a gallon of fuel for free
>   None

Why don't I receive 36 before the "Bring 10 coupons...." sentence and why does it return None?

Answer (score 4):

Because your wrapped function doesn't return anything - in python that means an implicit `return None`.

Fix:

```
def decor(func):
    def wraper(a):
        ret = func(a) # save return value
        print('Bring 10 coupons and get a gallon of fuel for free')
        return ret    # return it
    return wraper
```

Output:

```
Bring 10 coupons and get a gallon of fuel for free
36.0
```

Comment: but how to do to get the sentence below 36 not upon it? like this:
36  #the sentence under it#

Bring 10 coupons and get a gallon of fuel for free

Comment: The 36 will always come last since that's coming from `print(car_fuel(abc))` Decorator outputs can't come after the function has already finished executing.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the decorator. now it works properly thanks @rdas.

```
`def decor(func):
        def wraper(a):
            r=func(a)

            return str(r)+'\n'+'bring 10 coupons and get 10l free fuel'
        return wraper`
```